# Casting an AnyObject to a Dictionary nested in an Array

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, casting

I am looking to cast an AnyObject variable as a Dictionary nested in an Array.  For example, I declare the variable in my function:

```
var items: [[String:String]] = [
     [
         "pid": "1",
         "content": "123",
         "vote": "1",
         "city": "New York",
         "country": "United States"
     ]
 ]
```

Then I fetch a JSON object from an  HTTP request and convert it into an AnyObject.  Then I am trying to append the data fetched by the HTTP request as an AnyObject onto the original variable.

This process fails at the casting of the AnyObject into the desired [[String: String]] form.

```
func updateTable(data: AnyObject?) {
    let data_array = (data as! NSArray) as! Array<Dictionary<String, String>>

    self.items += data_array
}
```

This function include the casting of the variable and the addition of the arrays.

How can I cast this variable correctly?

**EDIT**
I forgot to mention that I cast my Serialized JSON Output as [AnyObject] before passing it through the function

Comment: Try this => let data_array = data as! NSDictionary

Comment: Its not compatible with with the original variable is [[String: String]]

Comment: Try this => data as Dictionary<String, String>

Comment: Also doesn't work, it says "cannot convert value of type [[String, String]] to expected argument type 'input_'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to cast the individual elements of the array.

```
func updateTable(data: [AnyObject]) {
for item in data {
    if let item = item as? [String: String] {
        items.append(item)
    }
}
```

Or if you want to be more concise...

```
func updateTable(data: [AnyObject]) {
    items += data.flatMap({$0 as? [String: String]})
}
```